# How to write stored procedures using tables from another schema?

Tags: oracle, schema

Is it necessary that table should be in HR user to call function and procedure of Oracle? When I run function from another user, it gives me a compilation error.

For my project,I want to run the function and procedure from another user. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a function or procedure using a table in another schema the table owner needs to grant us the required privilege.  For example:

```
SQL>  conn hr/hr
SQL>  grant select on employees to mousumi;
```

or ask a super user to do it for you:

```
SQL>  conn dba_user/password
SQL>  grant select on hr.employees to mousumi;
```

Privileges can be granted to roles but we cannot use those privileges to create procedures or views.  For that purpose the privileges must be granted directly  to us.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603).

When we reference that we need to include the schema name:

```
SQL>  select * from hr.employees;
```

Alternatively we can create a synonym for it.

```
SQL>  create synonym employee_table for hr.employees;
SQL>  select * from employee_table;
```

The synonym is just a label: it can be anything we like providing it is unique within our schema (and conforms to Oracle naming conventions). [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401).